# Custom/Built in Functions for Mixed Case/Camel Case in oracle

Tags: oracle, function, built-in

I have a requirement to treat the Name column in customized way based on the data as shown below. I need to Caps the Character that satisfies below cases do we have separate functions in oracle for these scenarios?

```
                   Check                                Example
1   First letter of each word is upper case (H & S in this example )        Hugo Smith
2   First letter following a space is upper case(B )    James A. Bond
3   First letter following a '/' is upper case(W, T)    Tonne/Wickey/Trisha
4   The 'II' and 'III' suffice are always all upper case    Larry III
5   First letter following an apostrophe is upper case(H)   Chris O'Harris
6   First letter following a dash is upper case(O)  Man-Oreoa
7   First letter following a '&' is upper case(T)   Hary,James&Tom
8   the acronym 'CFP' is always all upper case  Tanner, CFP
9   First letter following a period is upper case(P)    J.Paul
```

Comment: No, there is no magical function built in to oracle that will evaluate these validation requirements.  Write your own using built-in functions for string manipulation.

Comment: Please don't post your actual question (or requirements) as a screenshot. I can not even read the text in the scaled image.

Comment: INITCAP function worked fine for everything except for item 4 & 8

Answer (score 0):

INITICAP function has been used.
For remaining Items i have used INITICAP + REPLACE function